# How to Enumerate IEnumerable, comparing previous values against current values

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Note: There is quite a bit of text here but its additional information that may or may not be required.  If I don't include this, then responders ask for more information or make suggestions for approaches that may not work, due to my entire implementation.  If there is a better way to structure this so that all information is available, please let me know the best way to provide this supporting information.  The gist is that I am trying to is here:

I am building a program that will read files and determine an organization (internal org code) to associate each file to, based on a predefined list of orgs and how often each org shows up in the file.  The basic premise and current manual solution is:

### Manual Process

- Receive files in an unusual but overall consistent data format.
- Each file has data pertaining to an organization's transactions  (inbound and outbound types)
- Each row in the file represents a single transaction; however, the fields are not always in the same order.
- Goal is to determine which org "owns" the transactions (the entire file will be associated with this org at the end)
- To be determined as the transaction "owner", the org in question must show up the same amount of times on each row (e.g. if Org1 shows up twice on Row 1 and once on Row 2, it can't be our Org due to inconsistency).
- Nearly 100% of the time, the correctly associated Org has the highest frequency in the file, consistent across every row checked so programming this will give us a 99% solution.  We can refine it further, if needed, once these rules are implemented

So far in my project, I have implemented a class with the following members:

### My class thus far (summary of all logic at this point):

- Properties/fields

  - `_orgArray` - list of orgs to look for in each file
  - `_orgLength` - length of org code (used for iterating over character in file line and creating a buffer of specified length to check if  buffer value contains org)
- Methods

  - `GetDictIntersects` - accepts two dictionaries and returns a dictionary containing keys and values that exist in both input dictionaries
  - `GetLinesFromFile` - iterator that reads a file and yields a single lines from the file each iteration
  - `GetOrgCounts` - accepts a line of text (returned from `GetLinesFromFile`) and returns a dictionary containing each Org and its count of occurrences in the line of text
  - `ReduceOrgArray` - accepts a two dictionaries containing Org Counts (returned by `GetOrgCounts`) as well as an array of Orgs.  Returns a new array of orgs having removed any entries that  did not have consistencies amongst them (using `GetDictIntersects`) as well as any orgs that did not have any values > 0 (indicating no occurrences in lines of text)

### What the `DetermineOrg` method should do

To determine an Org for each file,  I'm working on a method named `DetermineOrg`.  My goal is to utilize the above methods and properties to

- starts with org array containing all potential orgs
- iterates the specified file (using `GetLinesFromFile`)
- reduces org array by removing orgs that don't meet criteria on each line by comparing the current line's org counts (returned from `GetOrgCounts`) with the previous line's org counts (using `GetDictIntersects` and `ReduceOrgArray`)
- Once file is iterated, if only a single Org remains in array, that is the return value
- If multiple Orgs remain, Org with highest count is returned.  If there is a tie, then Org (that tied with Max count) that shows up first in `_orgArray` is the return value

However, I can't seem to figure out the logic of how structure this so that I can recursively implement this.  My code for the method alone in question (in case you don't want the entire class)  is below.  Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing incorrectly and point me in the right direction:

### Stuck on this method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determine the appropriate organization for specified file
    /// Recursively apply the following business rules:
    /// <list type="number">
    /// <item>Initial run uses all Orgs</item>
    /// <item>Get Org Counts for each org on a line-by-line basis</item>
    /// <item>Compare each line's Org Counts with the previous line's Org Counts, removing any orgs from potential org list that do not have same counts on both lines</item>
    /// <item>After entire file has been read, determine a single Org by identifying which Org has the most occurences (highest value in dict)</item>
    /// <item>In case of ties, class member org array lists order of precedence.  Org with lowest index takes precedence.</item>
    /// </list>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath"><c>string</c> - file to be processed</param>
    /// <param name="numLines"><c>int</c>: 
    ///   Number of lines to be read from file in order to determine associated org.
    ///   Value less than 1 indicates to read the entire file.
    ///   Default value is -1 (read entire file to determine associated org).
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="orgArray"><c>string[]</c> representing potential orgs that file may be associated with</param>
    /// <param name="streamReader"><c>StreamReader</c> stream to specified file (read-only)</param>
    /// <param name="prevOrgCounts"><c>int</c> representing Org Counts for previous line of text</param>
    /// <returns><c>string</c> - represents org that file is associated with</returns>
    public static string DetermineOrg(string filePath, int numLines = -1, string[] orgArray = null, IEnumerable<string> streamReader = null, Dictionary<string, int> prevOrgCounts = null)
    {
        // base condition - no streamreader exists yet
        if (streamReader == null)
        {
            streamReader = GetLinesFromFile(filePath, numLines);
            // if no orgArray value is set, then use class member as starting value
            if (orgArray == null)
            {
                orgArray = _orgArray;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // get org counts from iterator
            foreach (string line in streamReader)
            {
                Dictionary<string, int> currentOrgCounts = GetOrgCounts(line, orgArray);
                // if we have previous and current counts, then get reduce orgs
                if (prevOrgCounts != null)
                {
                    orgArray = ReduceOrgArray(currentOrgCounts, prevOrgCounts, orgArray);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
        // base condition - if no counts yet, then get counts from filePath
        if (prevOrgCounts == null)
        {
            foreach (string line in GetLinesFromFile(filePath, numLines))
            {
                prevOrgCounts = GetOrgCounts(filePath, _orgArray);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Entire Class / All Code

The entire class can be found below.

```
using System;

namespace OrgProcessor
{

    internal class OrgProcessor
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// <c>string[]</c> containing list of orgs in order of precedence.  In case of ties between counts, order with lowest index takes precedence in org determination.
        /// </summary>
        static string[] _orgArray = { "Org1", "Org2", "Org3"};
        /// <summary>
        /// Length of Org (is consistent amongst orgs as each org is an "org code" representing an org that can be found in a lookup table.
        /// </summary>
        static byte _orgLength = 4;

        /// <summary>
        /// Compare 2 dictionaries and return a dictionary containing only keys and values that exist in both dictionaries.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dictionary1"><c>Dictionary<string, int></c></param>
        /// <param name="dictionary2"><c>Dictionary<string, int></param>
        /// <returns><c>Dictionary<string, int> - New dictionary containing key-value pairs that exist in both input dictionaries</returns>
        public static Dictionary<string, int> GetDictIntersects(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary1, Dictionary<string, int> dictionary2)
        {
            // only return entries that exist in both dictionaries
            Dictionary<string, int> returnDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (dynamic key in dictionary1.Keys)
            {
                // ensure key exists in other dictionary's keys AND values match in both dictionaries
                if (dictionary2.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    if (dictionary2[key] == dictionary1[key])
                    {
                        returnDict.Add(key, dictionary1[key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnDict;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Iterator method returning file content, line by line
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath"><c>string</c> - path to file to read from</param>
        /// <param name="numLines"><c>int</c> - number of lines to read from the file.  Negative numbers will be interpreted as "All Lines".  Default value is -1 (Read "All" lines)</param>
        /// <returns><c>IEnumerable</c><<c>string</c>></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetLinesFromFile(string filePath, int numLines = -1)
        {
            // TODO: Make more generic so iterator can take instructions to manipulate lines in file
            //     and optionally write to file (would need to write to temp, then delete orig and rename temp

            // track lines iterated
            int i = 0;
            // create reader
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                // yield line if not reached end of file AND
                //     num lines is not specified (i == -1) OR
                //     i (num lines return) has not exceeded num lines specified
                while (!reader.EndOfStream && (i < numLines || numLines == -1))
                {
                    yield return reader.ReadLine();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get number of times each org occurs in specified text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lineOfText"><c>string</c> of text to process</param>
        /// <param name="orgArray"><c>string[]</c> containing orgs to be counted</param>
        /// <returns><c>Dictionary<string, int></c> containing each Org and number of occurences in specified text</returns>
        public static Dictionary<string, int> GetOrgCounts(string lineOfText, string[] orgArray)
        {
            // instantiate return value
            Dictionary<string, int> orgCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            // get length of line of text as it will be referenced multiple times
            int textLength = lineOfText.Length;
            foreach (string org in orgArray)
            {
                //// set matchCount to 0
                //// int matchCount = 0;
                // since orgs are 4 characters long, iterate each character and compare with next 3 characters for each
                for(int i = 0; i < textLength; i ++)
                {
                    // get character at index
                    char c = lineOfText[i];
                    // calculate remaining characters
                    int remainingChars = textLength - i;
                    // char can only be part of an org if enough characters remain in lineOfText
                    if (remainingChars >= _orgLength)
                    {
                        // Get amount of chars that equals org length
                        string curCharBuffer = lineOfText.Substring(i, _orgLength);
                        // if characters match current org, then increment count dictionary
                        //   or add to dict with count of 1
                        if (curCharBuffer == org)
                        {
                            if (orgCounts.ContainsKey(org))
                            {
                                orgCounts[org] += 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                orgCounts.Add(org, 1);
                            }
                            // no need to evaluate other characters that were part of org so adjust loop incrementer to start next iteration after buffer
                            i += curCharBuffer.Length - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //// orgCounts[org] = matchCount;
            }
            return orgCounts;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Accepts 2 dictionaries (containing orgs and associated counts) and an array of strings (representing potential orgs) and returns a new string array having removed any "invalid" strings based on specified business rules:
        /// <list type="number">
        /// <item>If no orgs exist in array, return empty array</item>
        /// </list>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dictA"><c>Dictionary<string, int> containing orgs and counts</c></param>
        /// <param name="dictB"><c>Dictionary<string, int> containing orgs and counts</c></param>
        /// <param name="orgArray"><c>string[]</c> portential orgs</param>
        /// <returns><c>string[]</c> - represents potential orgs</returns>
        public static string[] ReduceOrgArray(Dictionary<string, int> dictA, Dictionary<string, int> dictB, string[] orgArray)
        {
            // base condition - if orgArray is empty, then return as is
            if (orgArray.Length == 0)
            {
                return orgArray;
            }
            // Return value
            List<string> remainingOrgs= new List<string>();
            // business rules require that org counts be same from record to record
            //  we can rule out potential orgs by removing those with inconsistent counts amongst records
            Dictionary<string, int> remainingDict = GetDictIntersects(dictA, dictB);
            // Iterate over remaining orgs
            //   remove those that don't have matching keys in remaining dict (showing inconsistency amongst recs)
            //   remove those with 0 counts (org must exist on all rows)
            foreach (string org in orgArray)
            {
                if (remainingDict.ContainsKey(org))
                {
                    if (remainingDict[org] > 0)
                    {
                        remainingOrgs.Add(org);
                    }
                }
            }
            // return remainingOrgs as array
            return remainingOrgs.ToArray();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Determine the appropriate organization for specified file
        /// Recursively apply the following business rules:
        /// <list type="number">
        /// <item>Initial run uses all Orgs</item>
        /// <item>Get Org Counts for each org on a line-by-line basis</item>
        /// <item>Compare each line's Org Counts with the previous line's Org Counts, removing any orgs from potential org list that do not have same counts on both lines</item>
        /// <item>After entire file has been read, determine a single Org by identifying which Org has the most occurences (highest value in dict)</item>
        /// <item>In case of ties, class member org array lists order of precedence.  Org with lowest index takes precedence.</item>
        /// </list>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath"><c>string</c> - file to be processed</param>
        /// <param name="numLines"><c>int</c>: 
        ///   Number of lines to be read from file in order to determine associated org.
        ///   Value less than 1 indicates to read the entire file.
        ///   Default value is -1 (read entire file to determine associated org).
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="orgArray"><c>string[]</c> representing potential orgs that file may be associated with</param>
        /// <param name="streamReader"><c>StreamReader</c> stream to specified file (read-only)</param>
        /// <param name="prevOrgCounts"><c>int</c> representing Org Counts for previous line of text</param>
        /// <returns><c>string</c> - represents org that file is associated with</returns>
        public static string DetermineOrg(string filePath, int numLines = -1, string[] orgArray = null, IEnumerable<string> streamReader = null, Dictionary<string, int> prevOrgCounts = null)
        {
            // base condition - no streamreader exists yet
            if (streamReader == null)
            {
                streamReader = GetLinesFromFile(filePath, numLines);
                // if no orgArray value is set, then use class member as starting value
                if (orgArray == null)
                {
                    orgArray = _orgArray;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // get org counts from iterator
                foreach (string line in streamReader)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, int> currentOrgCounts = GetOrgCounts(line, orgArray);
                    // if we have previous and current counts, then get reduce orgs
                    if (prevOrgCounts != null)
                    {
                        orgArray = ReduceOrgArray(currentOrgCounts, prevOrgCounts, orgArray);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            // base condition - if no counts yet, then get counts from filePath
            if (prevOrgCounts == null)
            {
                foreach (string line in GetLinesFromFile(filePath, numLines))
                {
                    prevOrgCounts = GetOrgCounts(filePath, _orgArray);
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see where recursion steps in there

Comment: ok, thanks for looking into.  Hopefully someone will know how to do this.

Comment: I mean: I do not see any part in your algorithm that would require or benefit from recursion. Looks all iterative to me.

Comment: Ok, recursion doesn't have to be the solution.  I'm not very experienced so I'm hoping that someone on this site that has experience can help me implement this method.  If recursion isn't the answer, then I'm sure there is a different way to do it; however, I'm not sure what that may be.  Hopefully someone has done something similar and can provide insight on how to implement this method.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked.  This was basically the final piece to the puzzle and now everything fits together:

```
public static string DetermineOrg(string filePath)
        {
            // Initialize variables to store previous line's org counts and current list of potential orgs
            Dictionary<string, int> previousLineOrgCounts = null;
            string[] potentialOrgs = _orgArray;

            // Iteratve over the file's lines using the GetLinesFromFile method
            foreach(string line in GetLinesFromFile(filePath))
            {
                // Get the org counts for the current line
                Dictionary<string, int> currentLineOrgCounts = GetOrgCounts(line, potentialOrgs);

                // Check if this is not the first line of the file
                if (previousLineOrgCounts != null)
                {
                    // reduce the list of potential orgs using the current and previous line org counts
                    potentialOrgs = ReduceOrgArray(previousLineOrgCounts, currentLineOrgCounts, potentialOrgs);
                }

                // update the previous line or g counts for the next iteration
                previousLineOrgCounts = currentLineOrgCounts;
            }

            // Check if only one org remains in the potential orgs list
            if(potentialOrgs.Length == 1)
            {
                // return the remaining org
                return potentialOrgs[0];
            }
            else
            {
                // Initialize variables to store the max org count and the org with the max count
                int maxOrgCount = 0;
                string orgWithMaxCount = null;

                // Iterate over the remaining potential orgs
                foreach (string org in potentialOrgs)
                {
                    // Check if the current org has a higher count that the previous max count
                    if (previousLineOrgCounts[org] > maxOrgCount)
                    {
                        // update the max org count and the org with the max count
                        maxOrgCount = previousLineOrgCounts[org];
                        orgWithMaxCount = org;
                    }
                }

                // Return the org with the max count
                return orgWithMaxCount;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly, you only keep track of the current list of candidates, but not the ocurrence count so you have nothing to compare to.

Here is my solution:

```
string[] orgs = { "ORG1", "ORG2", "ORG3"};

// This array will hold
// - either the number of times the corresponding organisation name occurs in each line
// - or 0 if the corresponding organisation name does not occur in any line
//   or occurs with different count in some lines
var orgCounts = new int[orgs.Length];

var readLines = 0; // the number of lines read so far (used to recognize the first line)
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < orgs.Length; i++)
    {
        // count the occurrences of orgs[i] in the read line
        var count = CountOccurrences(line, orgs[i]);
        if (readLines == 0)
        {
            // first line: just remember the count of occurrences
            orgCounts[i] = count;
        }
        else if (orgCounts[i] != count)
        {
            // mismatch, set count to 0
            orgCounts[i] = 0;
        }
        readLines++;
    }
}

// helper function to count the occurrences of toFind in str
int CountOccurrences(string str, string toFind)
{
    var count = 0;
    var index = str.IndexOf(toFind);
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        count++;
        index = str.IndexOf(toFind, index+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come up with that logic.  It is very much appreciated.  I actually did have a mthod to get the counts (GetOrgCounts), though.  With that being said, I now have a solution and will post that here.  Thanks again!